# Middle Sidebar Advertising

Tags: discussion, advertising, announcement

As you all know, advertising is an important source of revenue for Stack Overflow and it helps us support all the sites across the Stack Exchange Network and the resources that go into maintaining and improving the experience on the platform. We are going to be introducing middle sidebar ads, which have been on the main Stack Overflow site for years, to some of the tech sites including 3D Printing.

The middle sidebar ads have the same standards as any other ads on the platform. Ads are non-intrusive and static. Ads go through a vetting process to ensure they are appropriate for the communities on Stack Exchange. If you see an ad that may not follow our established standards and guidelines, you can let us know by using the "**report this ad**" functionality. Here is a mockup of what these will look like when two ads are showed (the existing ad placement and the new middle sidebar ad placement):

[image: sample of ads on the middle side bar of the site]

This ad space won’t be available for display until May 10 because we wanted to give you a heads-up before you started seeing them. Ads are an essential line of business for us and we’re committed to giving you advanced notice whenever we introduce a new form of advertising on the network sites. If you have any questions or concerns, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of random adds, is it possible to attract Stack specific/related adds e.g. contact 3D printer manufacturers for add space.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a reputation milestone of 200, [reduce ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads), which reduced the amount of visible advertising.

However, I notice that on our [Privileges page](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) it doesn't see to be there. I'm not sure if it was there previously, and has been removed, or was never there. I don't remember it being so, but was this just a privilege only on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @greenoline It's the leaderboard ads that aren't visible to people with 200+ rep who have that enabled. Side bar ads would still be visible as they are on SO stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads. These will display the same way as they have on SO.